# How to handle pointer of LinkedList in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new on C++, so here is a practice problem I'm trying to solve.
So i was planning to put a int in to a linkedlist digit by digit, here is what I wrote:

```
ListNode* listtest() {
     int i = 1234567;
     ListNode* head = NULL;
     ListNode** p = &head;
     while (i != 0) {
         int a = i % 10;
         ListNode* tmp = new ListNode(a);
         if (head == NULL) {
             head = tmp;
         }
         else {
             (*p)->next = tmp;
             p = &tmp;
         }
         i = i / 10;
     }
     return head;

 }
```

So it turns out this one will output a linkedlist with next is itself. But after I change `p = &tmp` into `p = &(*p)->next`, it work out well. As far as I see, both line change this pointer `p` to the next node after `p`. How could the outcome so different?

(Plus is there any recommend artical or video I can read to learn how to handle pointer in LinkList, cuz as beginner, it is pretty confusing.)

Answer (score 3):

`tmp` is a local variable in the `for` loop.

`(*p)->next` is the `next` pointer in the linked list node.

`(*p)->next = tmp;` sets one to the value of the other, but they are still two completely independent entities. A pointer to one of them is not logically equivalent to the pointer to the other one. You can think of them as identical twins, at this point. They look like. They talk alike. But pointing your finger at one of them is not equivalent to pointing your finger at the other one. They are separate entities, of their own. More importantly:

`p = &tmp;` - this sets `p` to point to `tmp`.

Which gets immediately destroyed. This is a local variable in the loop, and as soon as loop ends, this variable gets destroyed, even if the loop iterates again.

Attempting to access this object afterwards is undefined behavior, that will result [in demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Unless you like demons flying out of your nose, you should not do that.

Comment: I still couldn't understand why `(*p)->next = tmp ` are still two independent entities, so `tmp` here should be a pointer to this Node, and assign a pointer to another pointer shouldn't make them both point to same object?

Comment: They point to the same object, all right, but `tmp`, and `(*p)->next`, themselves, are two completely different entities; so `p = &tmp` versus `p = &(*p)->next` ends up setting `p` to point to ***different*** entities.